# Tool to replace URL with custom content

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, developer-tools

Is there a development tool or Chrome / Firefox extension that lets you replace the contents of a specific URL with my own custom content?

I'm not looking for a simple /etc/hosts file change, because I want to replace a URL, not just a domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[chrome.tab API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) will let you to make any related changes to a tab in a window.

### References:

[a) Tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html)

[b) Basic Chrome Extension architecture.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html)

You can refer this Sample Extension for changing all URL's in a current tab to [Google.co.in](https://www.google.co.in/)

#### manifest.json

*This is a core file where we register all chrome extension content, ensure it is with all permissions.*

```
{
"name":"Tabs Demo",
"description":"This Demonstrates Demo of Tabs",
"browser_action":{
"default_icon":"screen.png",
"default_popup":"popup.html"
},
"permissions":["tabs"],
"manifest_version":2,
"version":"1"
}
```

#### popup.html

Trivial HTML file referring to a JS file to pass CSP.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

#### popup.js

```
function tabsfunction() {
    //fetching all tabs in window
    chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(function (tabs) {
        // Iterating through tabs
        for (tab in tabs) {
            //Updating each tab URL to custom url 
            chrome.tabs.update(tabs[tab].id, {
                "url": /*You can place any URL you want here*/
                "https://www.google.co.in/"
            }, function () {
                //Call back
                console.log("Completed");
            });
        }
    });
}
//Binging a function on document events 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", tabsfunction);
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: The problem is that the content I want replaced is being loaded from within a JavaScript, so I'm not sure your solution will work for that. Would it?

Comment: @EduardLuca:Yes, it will work, if you can provide related code of your java script i can show that as well..

Comment: Found something that goes along with what you said, but didn't do exactly what I wanted, so I took that and modified it and got my stuff working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In a Chrome extension, the [`webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) API can be used to redirect URLs to a different URL. This other URL can be another online page, but also a page within your Chrome extension.
A simple example for the `webRequest` API, and a list of other options can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065029/chrome-redirect-extension/12070823#12070823).

Note: If you just want to add / change something on a specific page, [Content scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) may be more suitable. You can then change the content of a specific page by standard DOM methods.

In Firefox, you can use the [`page-mod`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html) module of the [Addon SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/) to implement the Content script.