# Chrome extension that captures and redirects anything typed in the URL/search bar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, google-chrome-extension

I would like to create an extension that will manipulate anything (mathching a pattern) typed in the URL bar and make an apriopriate redirect.

Being more specific:
I would like to type an URL of such format: `_http://<something>`. I would like chrome to redirect this `http://<something>`.

Here is what I came up with (basing on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065029/chrome-redirect-extension/12070823#12070823)):

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "_Replace",
  "description": "Replace '_http' with 'http'",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {"scripts":["background.js"]},
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "<all_urls>",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {

        var url = details.url;
        console.log(url);
        if(url[0] == "_")
         return {redirectUrl: url.substr(1)};
    },
    {
        urls: [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

Unfortunatelly since "_http://xxx" in a valid URL, google would automatically treat this as a search phrase and redirect me to google search. How could I prevent searching and make a redirect I want?

Comment: What about checking the url and if it's google search with the parameter `_http://xxx` then redirect it? I mean there's nothing else you can do anyway...

Comment: I thought about that, hoever I would have to extract the parameter and decrypt it. Probably would work fine. However I am wondering if this is the best and most general way - what if I change the search engine (probably wont happen, but...)? Maybe I should use the `tabs` object?

Comment: Well, yep, `decodeURIComponent` and so on. I don't see any better method. There's no API to read the omnibox (address bar).

Comment: @dstronczak I already [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065029/chrome-redirect-extension/12070823#comment54620909_12070823) to parse the search URL and redirect to your desired destination. wOxxOm independently reached the same conclusion. So I guess that this is indeed the best method.