# Can I have a splash page show when I search a URL in a chrome extension?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I want to show a splash page once I enter a URL and search. For example, if I go to https://youtube.com, then my Chrome extension will first show my splashpage.html. I was researching the override pages in the documentation, but it seems that I can only use "chrome_url_overrides" for new tabs, bookmark manager, and history.

My manifest.json has a newtab that opens up my "splashpage.html" when a new tab is entered. I would like to do this same action, but before the initial URL is loaded.

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Splash",
    "version": "1",
    "author": "LC",
    "browser_action": {  "default_title": "Have a good day", "default_popup": "popup.html" },
    "chrome_url_overrides" : {  "newtab": "splashpage.html"},
    "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could utilise url redirection instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065029/redirecting-url-in-a-chrome-extension

Comment: After further clarification of the feature from my lead, the URL redirection is definitely the way to go! Thank you!